# I'm trying to make an announcement command but getting an error

Tags: bots, discord, discord.js

So basically I'm trying to send an announcement to specific channel using `message.mentions.channels`
ex `!announce #announcements Today is a great day!`

Error:

```
(node:5516) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'channels' of undefined
    at Object.module.exports.execute (C:\Users\Zarko\Desktop\Stackoverflow\commands\Answers\announce.js:3:36)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Zarko\Desktop\Stackoverflow\events\message.js:20:30)
    at Client.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\Zarko\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\Zarko\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\Zarko\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:386:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\Zarko\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:436:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\Zarko\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:293:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\Zarko\node_modules\discord.js\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:125:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:223:5)
(node:5516) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:5516) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Code:

```js
    let channel = message.mentions.channels.first();
    if (!channel) return 
    let announcement = args.slice(1).join(" ");
  
    channel.send(announcement)
```

Comment: The error says it can't access the property channel of undefined, no where in the code you provide do you try to access ".channel", so we would need more code

Comment: Thats all I got

Comment: @Karizma got a solution?

Comment: That can't be all the code, unless you mistyped the error. it should tell you the line number, so add that line and relevant surrounding code for that line.

Comment: nevermind it works now, changed nothing and it works, anyways thanks for help

Comment: Nvm still getting the same error: (node:7588) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'channels' of undefined @Karizma

Comment: Does it say which line it's on? Is it the one where you declare let channel?

Comment: It doesn't, I assume its the one where I declared `"channels"` cuz error is saying `"Cannot read property 'channels' of undefined"`, so sending a message to a channel is fine

Comment: It probably does, edit your post and show the full error message, also log what message is and add it to the post

Comment: Done, a message is as I declared `announcement`, it works just fine

Comment: The error clearly says it's on line 3 of the execute function, the announcement variable is using args, and it's after the error so no, you don't know that it works. Just log message before the error and it to the post.

Comment: Yea but still if i remove the line 3 and do channel.send("this is a test") i still get the same error...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216452/discussion-between-karizma-and-rez).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error was how you passed in variables:

in one of your other command files you had:

```js
execute(client, message, args) {
  //this works
}
```

And in your announce command file you had:

```js
execute(message, args){
  console.log(message, args);

  /* =>
  Client {
   ...
  }

  Message {
   ...
  }
  */
}
```

So in this instance, message is the actual client object, and args is the actual message object, so simply just fix your variable spots,

Your new execute function in announce.js

```js
execute(client, message, args) {
  //rest of code here
}
```